# XSLT: copy certain nodes only

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, copy, filtering

Can you tell me how to peform this using XSLT ?

### Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<A>
  <BB bb1="bb1" />
  <CC cc1="cc1" />
  <DD name="name1">
    <EEE type="foo" value="50">
      <FFFF id="id1">
    </EEE>
  </DD>
  <DD name="name2">
    <EEE type="bar" value="50">
      <FFFF id="id2">
    </EEE>
  </DD>
  <DD name="name3">
    <EEE type="foo" value="40">
      <FFFF id="id3">
    </EEE>
  </DD>
```

### Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<A>
  <BB bb1="bb1" />
  <CC cc1="cc1" />
  <DD name="name3">
    <EEE type="foo" value="40">
      <FFFF id="id3">
    </EEE>
  </DD>
  <DD name="name1">
    <EEE type="foo" value="50">
      <FFFF id="id1">
    </EEE>
  </DD>
```

I.e. copy all except that if it is a DD, copy only if EEE/@type = "foo", and sort all DD by EEE/@value.

For now i've just found xsl code to copy everything and sort by say EEE/@type for example.

### XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
        <xsl:sort select="EEE/@type" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

That's already good enough but I really want to keep only those DD where EEE/@type = foo.

Thank You very much.

Comment: Could you post the XSLT code you currently have. Hopefully it should be only a minor tweak to the code to check the relevant @type attribute. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
        <xsl:sort select="EEE/@type" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

you just need to add a template

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
        <xsl:sort select="EEE/@type" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="DD[not(EEE/@type = 'foo')]"/>
```

that ensures those `DD` elements with `EEE/@type` not equal `'foo'` are not copied.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to select the nodes you want with xpath

This should only copy 'EEE' elements with attribute type=foo

```
<xsl:template match="//EEE[@type='foo']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```